# How to use a protocol with associated type with ObservableObject?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to create a protocol for something that must also conform to `ObservableObject`, which will live within another object `Services`:

```swift
protocol ThumbnailServiceProtocol: ObservableObject where ObjectWillChangePublisher == ObservableObjectPublisher {
    var processingThumbnails: [String] { get }
}

final class ThumbnailService: ThumbnailServiceProtocol {
    var processingThumbnails: [String] = []
}

struct Services {
    var thumbnailService: ThumbnailServiceProtocol
}

var services = Services(thumbnailService: ThumbnailService())
```

My problem comes when I try to swap out services to use a mock in my tests like this:

```swift
final class MockThumbnailService: ThumbnailServiceProtocol {
    var processingThumbnails: [String] = []
}

services = Services(thumbnailService: MockThumbnailService()) /// Cannot convert value of type 'MockThumbnailService' to expected argument type 'ThumbnailServiceProtocol'
```

I think the problem is coming from the fact that `ObservableObject` is a protocol with an associated type (`associatedtype ObjectWillChangePublisher`) but I thought I'd 'filled in the hole' by specifying `where ObjectWillChangePublisher == ObservableObjectPublisher`.

Am I missing something please?

Edit: to clarify, `services` is a global object which I'd like to swap out with a new instance of `Services` containing mocks in my unit tests, which is why I've tried to make this work:

```swift
var services = Services(thumbnailService: ThumbnailService())
services = Services(thumbnailService: MockThumbnailService()) /// Cannot convert value of type 'MockThumbnailService' to expected argument type 'ThumbnailServiceProtocol'
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your example is that `Services.processingThumbnails` is of type `ThumbnailService`, and not `ThumbnailServiceProtocol`. These types are not the same. You need to make `Services` generic. Try this:

```
protocol ThumbnailServiceProtocol: ObservableObject {
    var processingThumbnails: [String] { get }
}

final class ThumbnailService: ThumbnailServiceProtocol {
    var processingThumbnails: [String] = []
}

final class MockThumbnailService: ThumbnailServiceProtocol {
    var processingThumbnails: [String] = []
}

struct Services<T> where T: ThumbnailServiceProtocol, T.ObjectWillChangePublisher == ObservableObjectPublisher {
    var thumbnailService: T
}

let servicesA = Services(thumbnailService: ThumbnailService())
let servicesB = Services(thumbnailService: MockThumbnailService())
```

Comment: Whoops - I meant for `thumbnailService` to conform to `ThumbnailServiceProtocol` but I mis-typed, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Your answer works nicely thank you, but I'm using a global object `services` that I'd like to swap out in my unit tests. So I'm not creating a new variable (like your `servicesB`) but instead assigning a new instance of `Services` to `servicesA`. However, when making it generic it expects a `ThumbnailService` moving forward. Is there a way to make this work? Many thanks

Comment: In that case you might need to use type erasure and introduce an `AnyThumbnailService` type.